# Operator overloading with different datatypes in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Take this for example:

```
float operator+(int a, float b)
{
   return b + (float)a;
}

void main()
{
    int a = 10;
    float b = 2.5f;
    float c;

    c = a + b; //works as intended
    c = b + a; //results in type mismatch error
}
```

So my question:
Is there a way to have the parameters being accepted bidirectional without defining a second function?

Comment: Use a C++ template instead. Or change `int a` to `float a`.

Comment: Why are you capitalizing `Return`? And no, you need to define a second one because the language does not assume anything about your operators. Also, you probably don't want to overload that operator for int and float, that might make your code hard to read since you don't expect a custom function to be called when you add two numbers.

Comment: You need two operators, it doesn't work in a "bidirectional" way.

Comment: as a rule of thumb you shouldnt mess around with types that are not yours. In that sense, your example is not a good one, because the solution to this specific problem is to not implement your own `operator+` for `int` and `float` in the first place, then `+` will work as expected :P

Comment: It is not possible in standard C++ to overload `operator+()` unless at least one of the operands is of class type.  All overloads of `operator+()` that accept two arguments of basic type (such as `float operator+(int a, float b)`) are disallowed under the standard.    If your compiler allows that, it is a non-standard extension.    That said, the only way to get "bidirectional" operators is to provide both overloads.

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re asking since the code you’ve posted doesn’t actually compile, regardless of the error you’re asking about, because it contains *numerous* errors. What is it that you actually tried? Please post your *actual* code.

Comment: yes please try to be more clear on what is the actual problem you are trying to solve, your example is simplified to a point that the original problem is not obvious anymore. (to add an `int` and a `float` you need to write zero functions yourself)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to overload operators for fundamental types.
You should only overload operators for classes that you have defined.

A solution for overloading a binary operator for your own class with heterogeneous arguments symmetrically, is to define the operator for first type, and make the second type implicitly convertible to the first.

Answer (score -1):

Use float 'a' instead of int 'a',In default when adding int number to float it automatically assign higher precision. (Int + float outcome become float)

Comment: for the given example this answers the question literally, but I suppose `int` and `float` are just for the example. Consider `operator+(Foo f,Bar b)` (and the case where there is no obvious common type for `Foo` and `Bar` )

Comment: but if you take the quesiton literally, then it is completely pointless to write an `operator+` in the first place. Writing a function that adds two floats should not pass any code review